# How to extract value from selected TextBlock element in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I'm using a ListBox to display all values contained in Dictionary<> object:

```
<ListBox Height="519" x:Name="ContactsListBox" Width="460" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="ContactsListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="5" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name ="LastNameData" Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="20, 0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Content is filled by the following code:

```
Dictionary<long, Contact> contacts = new Dictionary<long, Contact>();
this.ContactsListBox.ItemsSource = contacts;
```

Now, I would like to 'know' which specific "Contact" in ListBox is currently selected, either by knowing its Key, or just by extracting value from "LastNameData" TextBlock.

I tried doing something like that, but obviosly it doesn't work:

```
private void ContactsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = this.ContactsListBox.SelectedItem as ListBox;
    this.Test_SomeOtherTextBlock.Text = lb.ToString();
}
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

In Xaml you probably don't want to display the class name, but a reasonable string, for example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name ="LastNameData" Text="{Binding Value.LastName}" Margin="20, 0" />
```

In the selection processing the selected item is KeyValuePair<...>. You could easily find it yourself, if you looked at the returned type in debugger. (Should be kind of a reflex for a programmer, hence a questions like above should never appear :))

```
private void ContactsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) { 
    KeyValuePair<long, Contact> kv = (KeyValuePair<long, Contact>)this.ContactsListBox.SelectedItem;
    Contact c = (Contact)kv.Value;
    Debug.WriteLine(c.LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can even do the follwing:

```
<ListBox Height="519" x:Name="ContactsListBox" Width="460" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name ="LastNameData" Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="20, 0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ContactsListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Margin="0,470,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </Grid>
```

So you don't need code behind...

BR,

TJ

Comment: Except the wrong binding used. Should be something like "{Binding Value.LastName}". But this concerns the original ListBox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, using `ListBox.SelectedItem` is the right approach.

I think the problem is that you should cast it as `ListBoxItem`, not `ListBox`. And also to get to its value using `DataContext`, so something like along these lines (not tested, I'm not sure about accessing `DataContext` value in the last line):

```
private void ContactsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = this.ContactsListBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
    var dataContext = lbi.DataContext;
    this.Test_SomeOtherTextBlock.Text = dataContext.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me, will help you to...

private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

{

ListBox ContactListBox = sender as ListBox;

ListBoxItem listBoxItem = ContactListBox .ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ContactListBox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;

if (listBoxItem == null)

{

```
            return;
```

}

TextBlock txtBlock = FindVisualChildByName(listBoxItem, "ListTextBlock");

MessageBox.Show(txtBlock.Text);

}

```
    private static T FindVisualChildByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string name) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            string controlName = child.GetValue(NameProperty) as string;
            if (controlName == name)
            {
                return child as T;
            }
            T result = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void ContactsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = this.ContactsListBox.SelectedItem as ListBox;
    this.Test_SomeOtherTextBlock.Text = lb.ToString();
}
```

will go something like this..

```
private void ContactsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = this.ContactsListBox.SelectedItem as ListBox;
    DataTemplate template=lb.ContentTemplate;
    //Now here you have to extract the content of the data template 
      and then you need to extract the TextBlock from that content.
```

}

This is just an overview of the functionality.*Sorry not able to post complete code.*